# ReactJS when user clicks the button, needs to catch and display the error from back-end to user without using Hooks useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, try-catch

Im new to react JS. when user clicks the button, needs to catch and display the error from back-end to user without using Hooks.

```
class createform extends React.component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.handlecreateform = this.handlecreateform.bind(this);
     }
   async handlecreateform(){
      try{
        // some logic happens;
      }
     catch(err){
       this.setstate({error});
     }
```

I don't know how to display this error in render and return to user. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please don't just re-post your question, instead [edit the former](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72598072/edit) to clarify and explain why the duplicate does not solve your issue

Comment: See Error Boundaries in React (https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html). But they do use `state`. (The linked questions do not cover this).